# Link two tables in one in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

```php
$category = Category::all();
$product = Product::all()->where('category_id', $category->name)->get();
```

Change category id from its name and link two tables in one in Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a view and pass the data instead of returning a collection:

```
return view('some.view', [
    $category => Category::all();
    $product => Product::where('category_id', $category->name)->get();
]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views

Also, when you do this:

```
$product=Product::all()->where('category_id',$category->name)->get();
```

You're loading all products from DB into memory and then filtering them because `all()` is executing the query. Do not do this.

Answer (score 3):

kindly refer to Laravel documentation regarding setting up relationships:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

The relation between `Category` & `Product` is one to many, so it will be:

```
// app/Category.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Comment: Then you can just use `Category::find(1)->products` as `Collection` of `Product` items related to category with ID of 1.